# SharePoint List Repeating Table

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, custom-form, form

I'm taking a paper survey and converting it into a SharePoint list. The survey has a table which looks like this:

[image]

IS there any way to create something like this in a list in Foundation without InfoPath?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a custom list and make a Datasheet View as default? And of course set the item level permission to "Read items that were created by the user" and "Create items and edit items that were created by the user".